# MS Excel: Sumproduct only visible rows (use sumproduct with subtotal(9,array))

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

Pretty straightforward.

I want to use a `SUMPRODUCT` but only for visible rows.

I've tried `=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A10, SUBTOTAL(9,B2:B10))` ... didn't work, even as an array formula.

I'm probably missing something obvious but ... why doesn't this work? How can I get this to work?

Comment: What do you mean by "visible"? Can you post up a screen shot. In the words of Tom Cruise, "Help me... Help you...".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for doing that, use the formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A10,SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(B2:B10,ROW(B2:B10)-MIN(ROW(B2:B10)),0,1)))
```

[image]

As said in comments: keep in mind that `SUBTOTAL` does not work with manually hidden rows. Only rows which are hidden due to a "filter" will be skipped in the calculation.

**EDIT**
Thanks to XOR LX: If increasing the parameter of `SUBTOTAL` by 100 it will also work with manually hidden rows. The formula then would be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A10,SUBTOTAL(109,OFFSET(B2:B10,ROW(B2:B10)-MIN(ROW(B2:B10)),0,1)))
```

Comment: Have you tested it?  It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: yes I have... just keep in mind that subtotal does not work with manually hidden rows. you need to filter the range

Comment: @Dirk Reichel Are you sure about that? Do you understand the difference between, for example, =SUBTOTAL(9, and =SUBTOTAL(109,?

Comment: @XORLX yes I am sure. If you run the the formula via evaluate formula you will see that column A is multiplied by column B while the filtered rows of column B will return as 0. This way only the products of the visible lines will be summed up. Still there is the possibility that I am wrong, but right now, I am sure that is exactly what the OP is looking for...

Comment: Yes, but that is not the same as saying that "subtotal does not work with manually hidden rows". It does, provided you apply the appropriate parameter.

Comment: @XORLX oh yes you are right... I completely missed that. Much thanks pinpointing this.

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A10,SUBTOTAL(109,OFFSET(B2:B10,ROW(B2:B10)-MIN(ROW(B2:B10)),0,1)))
```

It will work on both rows hidden manually or by filter.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are repeating already accepted answer? I'd recommend deleting this. I'd also recommend that you check the Help section answering and asking - good answers and questions are how you collect reputation. That will also help you understand why this isn't considered a good answer, and why the community may well decide to delete it if you don't.

Comment: The formulas are different! One uses 109, the other 9 in the subtotal. And the user explained the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can add a new column that outputs `0` or `1` if the row is hidden and add this array to the `SumProduct` formula.

Formula for the `IsHidden` column:

```
= IF( SUBTOTAL(103,A2)=1, 1, 0)
```